# Current location pointer is jumping i dump to resolve the issue

Tags: android, performance, shell, android-layout, android-fragments

> Current location pointer is jumping i dump to resolve the issue.I want to stop jumping the current pointer pointer.I want to show pointer without jumping situation.
>   I tried 4 days but not done this Task.

```
 private boolean initMap() {
    if (mMap == null && FirstTimeMapIniciate == 0) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


    }
    return (mMap != null);
}
```

> Here is OnLocationChange Code

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
            mp = new MarkerOptions();
            mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude()));
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location : " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (FirstTimeMapIniciate == 0) {
                gotoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 15);

                FirstTimeMapIniciate = 1;

            }
            AppUtill.UniqueId();
            new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://103.8.7/hajjapi/api/GPSLocator/GetLocations");

            if (AppStatus.getInstance(getContext()).isOnline()) {


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Turn On your WIFI ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

         /*   if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();

            }*/


        }
    };
    LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    request.setInterval(1000);
    request.setFastestInterval(1000);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, request, mListener);
}
```

Comment: Anyone help me please...

Comment: Help me please.......

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your logic as the first you don't need to call setMyLocationUpdate(true) at every location update.
The answer to your question as I'd say you need to implement your own service where you can apply your customized algorithm to filter out those jumps.